# Cannot retrive objectName from searchEntry when I update ldapjs to v3

Tags: javascript, node.js, ldap, ldapjs

I recently upgraded the package [ldapjs](https://github.com/ldapjs/node-ldapjs) from v2 to v3. When I search for a user attribute with searchEntry, I get an empty object, but all others functions worked without a problem, this is my code:

```
          client.search(adSuffix, searchOptions, async (err: any, res: any) => {
            assert.ifError(err);
            await res.on('searchEntry', async (entry: any) => {
             //
             //this part was working normaly with ldapjs v2
             //
             console.log("entry.objectName ",entry.objectName);
             //but now i get an empty object
            });
          });
```

Did someone had the same issue ? or know how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, I added .pojo to access to the object:

```
res.on('searchEntry', async (entry: any) => {
             console.log('entry: ' + JSON.stringify(entry.pojo.objectName));
}
```